# Add table to dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

Having a problem adding a table to a dataset, watching in debugger I read xml file into datatable all looks fine,  when add datatabe to dataset table/dataset ( using dataviewer ) first record looks good remaining records/fields contain a red ! mark.

```
fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(GlobalVar.compathver), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
DataTable CommentTable = new DataTable("Comment");
CommentTable.Columns.Add("ID",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
CommentTable.Columns.Add("Author",Type.GetType("System.String"));
CommentTable.Columns.Add("Date",Type.GetType("System.String"));
CommentTable.Columns.Add("Text", Type.GetType("System.String"));
CommentTable.ReadXml(fs);
dset.Tables.Add(CommentTable);
fs.Close();


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommentItems>
  <Comment id="1">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Author>Billy</Author>
    <Date>05/22/2009</Date>
    <Text>
      Comments about Bills Blog.
    </Text>
  </Comment>
  <Comment id="3">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Author>Samanth</Author>
    <Date>05/31/2009</Date>
    <Text>
      Comments about Sams Blog.
    </Text>
  </Comment>
  <Comment id="4">
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Author>BillBoy</Author>
    <Date>06/22/2009</Date>
    <Text>
      Comments about Bills Blog.
    </Text>
  </Comment>
  <Comment id="4">
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Author>Bill</Author>
    <Date>05/21/2009</Date>
    <Text>
      Comments about Lees Blog.
    </Text>
  </Comment>
  <Comment id="3">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Author>Bill</Author>
    <Date>6/3/2009 2:29:54 PM</Date>
    <Text>Bill's comment</Text>
  </Comment>
  <Comment id="4">
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Author>Bill</Author>
    <Date>05/25/2009</Date>
    <Text>
      Comments about Not Not Not Bills Blog.
    </Text>
  </Comment>
</CommentItems>
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: This ran prefectly fine for me. I bound the dset to a grdiview and got all 6 rows

Comment: This ran perfectly fine for me,  The only code changes I made were the locaton of the XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is this

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362994

When using the Dataset Visualiser to display a Dataset with multiple tables error providers are seen instead of the expected data when switching tables.

The initial table displays correctly. After switching to another table only the first line of data is displayed. every other line has an error provider with the error 'Debugger busy. Can't get value'.

This behaviour has been seen on multiple PCs since installing Service Pack 1 for VS2008.

If the window is resized so that the visualizer grid is not visble when the table is changed then the data is shown correctly.CommentsThanks for your feedback. We are escalating this bug to the product unit who works on that specific feature area. The team will review this issue and make a decision on whether they will fix it or not for the next release.